# The mean of positive half Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability

There is a Gaussian distribution $g(x)$, its mean is $\mu=0$ and the variance is $\sigma=1$. 
So what is the mean value of $f(x)=\max(0, g(x))$?

Sorry for the wrong discription. I meant the Half-normal distribution. Sorry for the troubles. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\max(0,g(x))$ is just $g(x)$ (since from what you've written it appears that $g$, as a function, is the density of a positive measure).

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Yikouniao, As the question is currently worded it is trivial (possibly nonsensical) because g(x) is always positive. However, if you intended what i have written about in my answer, please edit your question to make it clear to other readers and people who may contribute answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say '*the positive half*', you are intending to refer to the **positive values of independent variable $x$** of the Gaussian distribution, rather than the positive values of $g(x)$.

You can learn allow about the half-normal distribution at Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).  (Although the note that the conventional normalization constant for the half-normal distribution is double that of the standard normal distribution curve, to ensure that the integral of the half-normal distribution is still exactly unity).

Thus, using your notation, the mean of the positive half of the standard gaussian distribution is exactly $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}} $.